# Template Class Specialization: Additional Members

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to create a template class. But based on its data type, it should have an additional member variable. I've been trying different methods but could not find a solution.

Basically, the class will have 2 member variables: `a` and `b`. But if `DataType` is not `void`, it should have an extra member called `data`.

How can I achieve this?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename DataType>
class MyClass {
public:
    int a;
    char b;
};

template <typename DataType, typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<DataType, void>::value>::type>
class MyClass {
    DataType data;
};
```

Comment: `DataType data;` is not an extra member in your example.

Answer (score 2):

*But if DataType is not void, it should have an extra member called data.* - so `void` seems to be a specialization.

```
template <typename DataType>
class MyClass {
public:
    int a;
    char b;
    DataType data;
};

template <>
class MyClass<void> {
public:
    int a;
    char b;
};
```

---

If I understood correctly, there is a way to "extend" your class members, if you "don't want to repeat yourself":

```
template <typename DataType>
class MyClass;

template <>
class MyClass<void> {
public:
    int a;
    char b;
};

template <typename DataType>
class MyClass : public MyClass<void> {
public:
    DataType data;
};
```

But `void` is still not your primary template, but a specialization. Since, different specializations are completelly different types in the end, you can publically inherit a specialization in your primary class template definition, thus extending those members.

Comment: You can call it that way, but I did not want to re-write all members and wondered if I could extend my primary template.

Comment: @ximeyox123 then you should be more clear on what you want and provide an expected usage example.

Comment: @ximeyox123 I've updated my answer. Is it what you want?